# Execute PHP-File once on ButtonClick - Android

Tags: php, android, file, execute, buttonclick

I have a value on a database and can finally display it in a textView, now i want to update that number on buttonclick.

The php-scripts work fine, if I open them in my browser and check my DB, the value changed +1.

Now my question is:: How can i execute this file from my android app? I don't want to read it, I just want to execute the file once, so that the value in the DB changes. I tried it this way:

public void updateData(String uri) {

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connn.connect();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my PHP-File but as mentioned before it works fine::

/*

```
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
if(!$con)
    {
    die('could not connect to database' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('vehicles', $con);

    $plusOne = ("UPDATE `counter` SET cars = cars + 1 WHERE id = 1;");

    mysql_close($con);

    ?> */
```

EDIT:: Ok nevermind everything works fine now :)

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Is your server returning the php file contents instead of executing it when you request it from your android app?

Comment: The server is returning nothing, so I think I dont even execute the php script correctly.

Comment: I simply want to run this PHP-Script on buttonclick so my database gets updated..